# show data base value in each column of excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to extract my database values to excel ..so i given code like this:

```
 sql = "select * from  tbl_ItemTransfer"
            cmd1 = New SqlCeCommand(sql, cn)
            dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader()

            ListBox1.Items.Add("Extracting " & strfilename)
            ListBox1.Refresh()
            While (dr.Read())

                sw = New StreamWriter(hht_Storage & "\Export\" & strfilename & ".xls", True)
                prcount = 0
                fvalues = ""
                For I = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
                    If fvalues = "" Then
                        fvalues = IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                        fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                    Else
                        fvalues = fvalues & "|"
                        fvalues = fvalues & IIf(IsDBNull(dr(I)), "", dr(I))
                        fvalues = Trim(Replace(fvalues, "'", ""))
                    End If
                Next I

                sw.WriteLine(fvalues)
                prcount = prcount + 1
                sw.Close()
            End While
```

so all of my values coming in one column separated by  "|". Instead of this i want to show all of my value in each column.how i can do that?
any help is very appreciable..

Answer (score 0):

use the `string.split` method to split the values.

id put the output into an array/data table to split the rows up easily.

then you can write the split values to your excel sheet, row by row.

hope this gets you a little further.